# JQ Expression to filter inside array with field outside the array

Tags: json, jq

My JSON is like so:

```
{
    "form" : {
        "state" : "MH"
    },
    "xls":[
        {
            "state": "MH",
            "channel" : 1,
            "city": "Pune"
        },{
            "state": "MH",
            "channel" : 1,
            "city": "Nashik"
        },{
            "state": "MH",
            "channel" : 2,
            "city": "Solapur"
        },{
            "state": "MH",
            "channel" : 2,
            "city": "Nagpur"
        },{
            "state": "KAR",
            "channel" : 1,
            "city": "Mysore"
        },{
            "state": "KAR",
            "channel" : 1,
            "city": "Bijapur"
        },{
            "state": "KAR",
            "channel" : 2,
            "city": "Bellary"
        },{
            "state": "KAR",
            "channel" : 2,
            "city": "Mangalore"
        }
    
    ]
    
    
}
```

Now, I want to find all the cities inside the xls array where the value is equal to form.state. I want to create a jq expression which can do this.

I tried :

```
    .xls[] | select(.state == .form.state) | .city
```

But this wont work since .form.state is outside.

I don't really want to pass arguments to my JQ expression. Is there any neat way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in two stages. Use a variable placeholder for the state name and use it again while matching the array of entries inside `xls`

```
.form.state as $c | .xls[] | select(.state == $c).city
```

Your attempt doesn't work, because once you descend into the `xls` leaf path, there is no way to get the value of `.form.state`, unless you store it in a variable.

https://jqplay.org/s/SSkOvKywcUa

Comment: Can the same thing be done in jmespath?

Comment: `jq` doesn't support jmespath. It has its own DSL